# How to write and read a list to a file? Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pickle

I have a problem with a program, that I wrote on my own, which checks your knowledge in Vocabulary. You can create a session with as many vocabulary as you want and you can write these words and their answers and if you have finished with writing this vocabulary the program can ask you these words and you should write the solution in the other language. The words are saved in 2 lists (1 list for the first language and the other list for the solutions of every word in the other language). And everything works fine, but if you close the program, your words will not be saved. And I wanted to save these lists in .txt files. Creating a .txt file works, but I can’t insert a list into a .txt file, it says that this should be a string. I tried many methods but I still get some errors. And I want both of the lists in one file and when I read them, they should be separated somehow. 
I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!!!

I tried the basic file.write and file.read method, but I get some errors, which say, that it can't be a list, it must be a string.
I also tried the join() Method, not working.
And I can't use pickle, because I have two lists in 1 file and they must be separated.

```
import random
import os.path 

firstList = []
secondList = []
sprachen = ["Afrikaans", "Albanisch", "Amharisch", "Arabisch", "Armenisch", "Aserbaidschanisch", "Baskisch", "Bengalisch", "Birmanisch", "Bosnisch", "Bulgarisch", "Cebuano", "Chichewa", "Chinesisch", "Mandarin", "Dänisch", "Deutsch", "Englisch", "Esperanto", "Estnisch", "Filipino", "Finnisch", "Französisch", "Friesisch", "Galizisch", "Georgisch", "Griechisch", "Gujarati", "Haitianisch", "Hausa", "Hawaiisch", "Hebräisch", "Hindi", "Hmong", "Igbo", "Indonesisch", "Irisch", "Isländisch", "Italienisch", "Japanisch", "Javanisch", "Jiddisch", "Kannada", "Kasachisch", "Katalanisch", "Khmer", "Kirigisch", "Koreanisch", "Korsisch", "Kroatisch", "Kurdisch", "Kurmandschi", "Lao", "Lateinisch", "Latein", "Lettisch", "Litauisch", "Luxemburgisch", "Malagasy", "Malayalam", "Malaysisch", "Maltesisch", "Maori", "Marathi", "Mazedonisch", "Mongolisch", "Nepalesisch", "Niederländisch", "Norwegisch", "Paschtu", "Persisch", "Polnisch", "Portugiesisch", "Punjabi", "Rumänisch", "Russisch", "Samonaisch", "Schottisch-Gällisch", "Schwedisch", "Serbisch", "Sesotho", "Shona", "Sindhi", "Singhalesisch", "Slowakisch", "Slowenisch", "Somali", "Spanisch", "Suaheli", "Sundanesisch", "Tadschikisch", "Tamil", "Telugu", "Thailändisch", "Tschechisch", "Türkisch", "Ukrainisch", "Ungarisch", "Urdu", "Usbekisch", "Vietnamesisch", "Walisisch", "Weissrussisch", "Xhosa", "Yoruba", "Zulu"] 

print("Willkommen beim Vokabelprogramm. Viel Spass beim Lernen!")

def start():
    global name
    projekt = input("Möchten Sie eine bestehende Lerneinheit öffnen [Open] 
    oder eine neue Lerneinheit beginnen [New]? ")
    if projekt == "Open":
        openProject = input("Welche Lerneinheit möchten Sie öffnen? ")
        while os.path.exists(openProject + ".txt"):
            name = openProject
            output()
        else:
            erstellen = input("Diese Lerneinheit existiert unter diesem Namen noch nicht. Möchten Sie diese erstellen? ")
            if erstellen == "Ja":
                name = openProject
                file = open(name + ".txt", "w+")
                file.close()
                print("Die Lerneinheit, namens " + name + ", wurde erstellt.")
                sprache()
            else:
                print("Die Aktion wird abgebrochen.")
                start()
    elif projekt == "New":
        name = input("Wie möchten Sie diese Lerneinheit nennen? ")
        while name == "":
            print("Geben Sie für den Namen Ihrer Lerneinheit einen gültigen Wert ein.")
        else:
            while os.path.exists(name + ".txt"):
                bestaetigung = input("Dieser Dateiname existiert bereits, möchten Sie diese Datei überschreiben? ")
                if bestaetigung == "Ja":
                    file = open(name + ".txt", "w+")
                    file.close()
                    print("Die Lerneinheit, namens " + name + ", wurde erstellt.")
                    sprache()
                else:
                    print("Die Aktion wird abgebrochen.")
                    start()
            else:
                file = open(name + ".txt", "w+")
                file.close()
                print("Die Lerneinheit, namens " + name + ", wurde erstellt.")
                sprache()
     else:
        print("Diese Eingabe ist ungültig.")
        start()

def sprache():
    global ersteSprache
    global zweiteSprache
    ersteSprache = input("Welche ist die erste Sprache, in der Sie die Vokabeln prüfen möchten? ")
    while ersteSprache in sprachen:
        zweiteSprache = input("Und die zweite Sprache? ")
        while zweiteSprache in sprachen:
            while zweiteSprache == ersteSprache:
                print("Sie müssen 2 verschiedene Sprachen angeben!")
                zweiteSprache = input("Welche ist die zweite Sprache? ")
                while zweiteSprache in sprachen:
                    beginning()
                else:
                    print("Diese Sprache gibt es nicht! Versuchen Sie die Sprachen nochmals einzugeben.")
                    sprache()
            else:
                beginning()
        else:
            print("Diese Sprache gibt es nicht, bitte versuchen Sie es nochmals.")
    else:
        print("Diese Sprache gibt es nicht, bitte versuchen Sie es nochmals.")
        sprache()

    def beginning():
    vokabel = input("Geben Sie eine Vokabel auf " + ersteSprache + " ein: ")
    if vokabel == "":
        print("Bitte geben Sie für die Vokabel einen gültigen Wert ein.")
        beginning()
    firstList.append(vokabel)
    uebersetzung = input("Was bedeutet diese Vokabel auf " + zweiteSprache + "? ")
    if uebersetzung == "":
        print("Bitte geben Sie für die Übersetzung einen gültigen Wert ein.")
        uebersetzung = input("Was bedeutet diese Vokabel auf " + zweiteSprache + "? ")
    secondList.append(uebersetzung)
    def abfrage():
        fertig = input("Ist das alles? Geben Sie Ja ein um die Vokabelliste zu bestätigen oder drücken Sie die Enter-Taste um noch eine Vokabel hinzuzufügen: ")
        if fertig == "Ja":
            with open(name + ".txt", "w") as file:
                for combo in zip(firstList, secondList):
                    file.writelines(" ".join(combo) + "\n")
            output()
        elif fertig == "":
            beginning()
        else:
            print("Diese Eingabe ist ungültig, bitte versuchen Sie es nochmals")
            abfrage()
    abfrage()

    def output():
    newLanguage_1 = []
    newLanguage_2 = []
    with open(name + ".txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            word_1, word_2 = line.split()
            newLanguage_1.append(word_1)
            newLanguage_2.append(word_2)
    ausgabe = random.choice(newLanguage_1)
    print(ausgabe)
    zahl = newLanguage_1.index(ausgabe)
    pruefen = input("Übersetzung: ")
    vokabelZweiteSprache = newLanguage_2[zahl]
    def nochmal():
        nochmals = input("Möchten Sie noch eine Vokabel prüfen (ENTER-Taste)? ")
        if nochmals == "":
            output()
        else:
            print("Viel Glück bei der Prüfung, Daumen sind gedrückt!")
            exit()
    if pruefen != vokabelZweiteSprache:
        print("Leider falsch! Die richtige Lösung wäre " + vokabelZweiteSprache + " gewesen. Lernen Sie diese Vokabel nochmals!")
        nochmal()
    else:
        print("Richtig! " + ausgabe + " heisst " + vokabelZweiteSprache + ".")
        nochmal()
start()
```

@Kraay89
Here I will post my relevant code for the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range` [Edit] I checked if the list is empty and it is, but I don't know why, I assigned it in the code, where is the problem:

```
new_currLanguage = []
with open(name + ".txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for lines[0] in file.readlines():
        lang_1, lang_2 = lines[0].split()
        new_currLanguage.append(lang_1, lang_2)
firstLanguage = new_currLanguage[0]
secondLanguage = new_currLanguage[1]
```

Comment: Please share your code... and the error you are getting

Comment: "The words are saved in 2 lists (1 list for the first language and the other list for the solutions of every word in the other language)" => wrong design. You want a list of `(original_word, translated_word)` instead. Else if for whatever reason any of the two lists changes and the change is not reported in the other then your data are corrupted.

Comment: I can post it, but I know that this is not working, because I tried many things.

Comment: I can post my code, but I wrote the prints and Inputs in German and some variables are in German.

Comment: "is not working" is the least possible useful description of an issue. Please read about [mcve] and edit your question accordingly ;-)

Comment: "Hello doctor, what's wrong with me?" - "Well, can I examine you first before jumping straight to diagnosis?" - "Well, if you have to, but I have already taken some pills and they didn't work..." :P

Comment: @user12141817, don't hesitate to share code that has foreign language variable names. The challenge is in the programming which is done all in the same python syntax we all speak. ;-) Also, I speak a bit of german.

Comment: For future: if the only obstacle is "I can't use pickle, because I have two lists in 1 file and they must be separated", this works: `pickle.dump([l1, l2], f)`, `l1, l2 = pickle.load(f)`.

Comment: Alright, I will keep it in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some code sample in the question i'm assuming a few things.

You probably tried writing the whole list to a file at once, but that is not the best way to approach this problem. Leaving out some of the suggestions in the comments, like how your data structure might be flawed, I think you could use the following code to get started, and improve from there.

Some key functions I use that you might be unfamiliar with:

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) -> to iterate over two lists at the same time

[str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) -> to join two string together, in this case with a space: `" "`

[str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) -> to split a string on any whitespace character

```
language_1 = ["Hello", "Bye", "Bike", "Car"] # English words
language_2 = ["Hallo", "Doei", "Fiets", "Auto"] # Dutch words

# Saving the lists:
with open("saved_lists.txt", 'w+') as myfile:
    for combo in zip(language_1, language_2):
        myfile.writelines(" ".join(combo)+"\n")

# Reading back:
new_language_1 = []
new_language_2 = []
with open("saved_lists.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        word_1, word_2 = line.split()
        new_language_1.append(word_1)
        new_language_2.append(word_2)
```

Comment: There is one problem with this solution. If I have a "word" which consists of more than 1 word (hard to explain). Example: go to school                                                             This doesn't work, I get an error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: That's why you need to update your question with some examples and the code you used. We can't just magically smell what your problems are or might be down the line. Look into the split and join functions. The combination of them will give you tools to deal with your problem.

Comment: I could post my code, but most of it is in German and most of the code is actually irrelevant for my problem, but I can post it.

Comment: Posted it above!

Comment: I stand by what I said earlier. Join and split will help you out... ;-) Google your errors, without the specific numbers for you case. `ValueError: not enough values to unpack` for example will till you all you need to know to fix your issue. Your code show that you have some experience already, so i'm sure you can work it out. compared to all the code you have written, this should be an easy problem to fix.

Comment: Hey, I have one more question based on this code. I want that the program starts to write everything in line 2 in this file and not in the first line, because in the first Line I want to have two values, which are my two languages. And I don't want to overwrite them with the words. I am now very confused and don't know exactly how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the documentation for the [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open) function. The help you seek is in there ;-)

Comment: Yeyy, I found it out. Just changed it to "append". Now I do the same method like above. I import the 2 values into a list and I am trying to receive the values from the list. But I get an error: IndexError: list index out of range                                 And here is the problem:    firstLanguage = new_Language[0]                              I can't get it, what is the problem???

Comment: I edited my question, so this problem is in my original question :)

Comment: Adding extra questions to your old questionisn't a good idea. This cause confusion for people who look at it later at a later stage.  Please remove it and maybe post a new question :)

Comment: I can't post a new question!

Comment: "You have reached your question limit" but I just posted 1 question more than 24 hours ago. 26 or more